# How do I take derivatives in Wolfram Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to learn a little bit about Wolfram Mathematica.

I want to define a symbolic function

[image: f(x)=h(C*g(Ax+b)+d)]

where *x* is a vector, *g* is a function that takes a vector and returns a vector and *h* is a function that takes a vector and returns a scalar.

I don't want to commit to specific *g* and *h*, I just want to have a symbolic representation for them.

I would like to get a symbolic form for the third order derivatives (which would be a tensor) -- is there a way to do that in Wolfram Mathematica?

EDIT: I should mention, *A* and *C* are matrices, and *b* and *d* are vectors.

Here is what I tried and didn't work:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
f[x_] := x*E^x
```

and then this

```
f'[x]
```

returns this

```
E^x + E^x x
```

and this

```
f''[x]
```

returns this

```
2 E^x + E^x x
```

Answer (score 0):

Three methods of notation, all producing the same result.

```
f[x_] := Sin[x] + x^2

D[f[x], x]
```

> 2 x + Cos[x]

```
f'[x]
```

> 2 x + Cos[x]

```
f''[x]
```

> 2 - Sin[x]

using an alternative form of definition of `f`

```
Clear[f]

f = Sin[x] + x^2

D[f, x]
```

> 2 x + Cos[x]

```
δx f
```

> 2 x + Cos[x]

```
δ{x,2} f
```

> 2 - Sin[x]

Note

`δ{x,2} f` is supposed to be the subscript form of `D[f, {x, 2}]` but web formatting is limited.

Scoping out matrix and vector dimensions, and using `S` instead of `C` since the latter is a protected (uppercase) symbol.

```
A = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};
x = {2, 4, 8};
A.x
```

> {34, 76}

```
b = {3, 5};
h = 3;
h (A.x + b)
```

> {111, 243}

```
S = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};
S.(h (A.x + b))
```

> {597, 1305, 2013}

```
d = {2, 4, 8};
g = 2;
g (S.(h (A.x + b)) + d)
```

> {1198, 2618, 4042}

So compatible [matrix and vector assumptions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Matrices.html) can be made.  (It turns out the derivative result comes out the same without taking the trouble to make the assumptions.)

```
Clear[A, x, b, S, d]

$Assumptions = {
  Element[A, Matrices[{m, n}]],
  Element[x, Vectors[n]],
  Element[b, Vectors[m]],
  Element[S, Matrices[{n, m}]],
  Element[d, Vectors[n]]};

f = g (S.(h (A.x + b)) + d);

D[f, x]
```

> g S.(h A.1)

```
D[f, {x, 3}]
```

> 0

I'm not sure if these results are correct so if you find out do comment.